# R: Clustering data of mixed types when N is large (1+ million rows)

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I seem to be stuck trying to cluster my data of 1+ million rows, with columns of both continuous (e.g. age) and categorical (e.g cats, dogs, birds) types.
It looks like daisy() from the cluster package generally is the go-to method when N is small, but I cannot seem to find any method when N is large.

daisy creates an NxN matrix, so that my R session can't allocate the memory,

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1343.0 Gb

, and I can't use k-means because of my mixed data types.

Could anybody help me here?

**EDIT**: I see one potential solution to my problem. I could for example use 10% of my data, use daisy() and then hclust or dbscan, but how would I then get the group "rules" out (or the partitions), such that I could use them on my whole data set? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any method that uses pairwise distances will need too much memory for large data. That is why there exist database-oriented methods such as DBSCAN and OPTICS that can -in good implementations- be used *without* computing all pairwise distances. Just your average implementation may not be good enough out-of-the-box. You'll have to spend effort to accelerate this for your distance.

Before spending time on making this fast, I would strongly suggest to first make it *work*. So **do not begin with the entire data set**. Begin with a sample and learn to get working results. Then decide whether they are good enough, and if you really need to scale this to the entire data. Most of the time, when you think you need to cluster "big data", then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that! Could you elaborate on the last sentence?

Comment: Clustering is explorative, and looking for frequent/typical patterns. If you have lots of data, it will still be discoverable in a subset, so it is sufficient to use a reasonably sized subsample. All "big data" is just hype; and people tend to scale methods without doing the second step: using their results in a meaningful way.